# Pairing users with filters

Tags: sql, postgresql, redis, subquery

I'm trying to pair up users that are announcing themselves at different times. Here is what I'm currently doing in **pseudo code**:

Here is my `attempts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE attempts (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  target_id integer NOT NULL,
  status smallint NOT NULL,
);
```

And the logic:

```
// Try to match someone that is available
//  - $match = UPDATE attempts set status = STATUS_MATCHED, target_id = [my user id] where status = STATUS_AVAILABLE limit 1;
// If you didn't find anyone then announce yourself
//  - $row_id = INSERT into attempts values (null, [my user id], null, STATUS_AVAILABLE);
// wait a bit of time
// Disable your announcement
//  - UPDATE $row set STATUS_FORFEIT if status = STATUS_AVAILABLE
// Grab your row again and see if you matched someone or if you are a forfeit
//  - SELECT status,target_id from attempts where id = $row_id;
```

This works great and people get matched. But we have a feature where you can block certain people. So now I need to check a blocked list too so that you aren't matching someone that has blocked you or that you have blocked (both directions).

```
CREATE TABLE blocked (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  target_id integer NOT NULL,
  active boolean NOT NULL,
);
```

So what's the best way to solve this problem? The only thing I can think of is a sub select where you are doing something like:

```
UPDATE attempts
SET status = STATUS_MATCHED, target_id = [my user id]
WHERE status = STATUS_AVAILABLE
AND (
    //and Where the following query return 0 rows
    //SELECT FROM blocked where user_id in ([my user id], attempts.user_id)
    // AND target_id in ([my user id], attempts.user_id)
    // AND active = true
)
LIMIT 1;
```

Using postgresql if that changes things. I also have a redis database available if this type of operation is better suited for something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE a
    SET status = STATUS_MATCHED,
        target_id = [my user id]
    FROM attempts a 
    WHERE a.id in (SELECT id
                   FROM attempts a2
                   WHERE a2.status = STATUS_AVAILABLE AND
                         NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                     FROM blocked b
                                     WHERE b.user_id in ([my user id], a2.user_id) AND
                                           b.target_id in ([my user id], a2.user_id) AND
                                           b.active = true
                                    )
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

The hard part in Postgres is implementing the `limit` logic in an `update`.  This does so using a subquery with a comparison to the primary key.  Note that an arbitrary matching row is updated.  You might want to make this explicitly random by including an `order by random()` just before the `limit 1`.

Comment: This is getting pretty messy. Maybe it's better to use a stored procedure or redis. My major concern was a race condition where while searching for a match in the table someone else grabs it. So I had the idea to do an immediate update. While this works in MySQL, it looks tedious in postgres...

Comment: @SteveTauber . . . This shouldn't be particularly tedious.  Joins on primary keys are very fast and if you have an index on `(active, user_id, target_id)`, then the query should perform well.

Comment: Yeah everything will be indexed since disk space is cheap :)

Comment: Just a heads up, I didn't need the `JOIN` and used `RETURNING`. Also your params are unbalanced.